# Output W3C compliant XHTML from image slices

Tags: xhtml, graphics, w3c, photoshop

When slicing and saving for web in Photoshop CS4, the HTML layout output by Photoshop is done using  tags, which is not what we want. Is there a way to get Photoshop to output W3C compliant tableless XHTML with CSS?

Alternatively, is there another application that I can use to slice to W3C XHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here, actually, this following URL is going to:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/fireworks/articles/fireworks_web_design_css.html

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder how clean the HTML generated is. My experience with WYSIWYG editors has been pretty underwhelming in the past. And the author of the article suggests this only as a way to generate mock-ups before you write the actual code for the pages. Though Dreamweaver definitely produced better markup than Frontpage so maybe Fireworks is just as good.